# Network call for Encoding type in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, networking

Iam new to swift and pretty confused.How to write a generic network method for post method to encode an object of type struct in swift 4 .As I have written a method which takes a parameter post of type login where login is the struct of type Codable. I need to make it generalised instead of only accepting login type.

Comment: Please consider posting the code, or part there0f, that doesn't work or needs to be modified. From what I understand, you are looking to create a generic API service layer or wrapper that can handle multiple API endpoints, is that correct Kushi ?

Comment: yea absolutely Mehul ..am a little confused in swift 4

Comment: class NetworkManager {
    func submitPost(post: Login, url:String,completion:((Error?) -> Void)?) {     /*network code here*/ }}

Comment: It is generally recommended to have separate functions for each endpoint, however the configuration can be injected into a single class, and this class may then be used as a singleton or whatever. Amongst other things, make the code more testable.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would begin by injecting the session object to this service class. You also provide the request block, and the completion blocks. In your case, you might considering using generics.

```
func doURLsessions(completionHandler: @escaping (SomeType?)->()) {
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
if let timeurl = URL(string: "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/NSE/NIFTY_50.json?api_key=xMH7BiBu6s24LHCizug3") {
    (session.dataTask(with: timeurl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else if let data = data {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try? jsonDecoder.decode(YourCodableStruct.self, from: data)
            if (response?.data != nil) {
                //process data, call the completion handler.
            }
        }
    })).resume()
}
```

You would typically have a separate function for each endpoint, all within the same class.

Comment: thanks Mehul..but my doubt was regarding encoding.How to send generic object using jsonencoder?